# How to compare two lists to determine if they have required values on the same index

Tags: c#

I have two lists xList and yList. They are used for storing coordinates. I need to get user input and ascertain if the values given by user (x, y) are in the lists (x in xList and y in yList). If the x variable is in xList and y in yList I need to know if they are at the same index. I was thinking that I would get every index of variable specific for the list and then compare indexes form both lists to find out if the user input match coordinates in lists. If there is a match the output will be index where the match is. Otherwise, the output will be -1. Example: xList is filled with numbers 5,5,2,2 the yList with 4,3,2,1. User input is x=5 and y=1. We know that 5 is in xList on index 0 and 1. One is in yList at index 3. So we know, that the numbers are in the lists but not on the same indexes therefore the output is -1. Then the user give us input x=5 and y=3. We know, that in xList are indexes 0 and 1. In yList is index 1. So the match is the index 1 and the output is 1. The way to do it is probably LinQ. But C# and OOP overall isn't my cup of tea and I can't make heads or tails out of it. But I also need to finish this. Is there any good soul, that would help me?

Comment: You didnt post anything (like code) for anyone to "help" with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a list of Coordinates like:

```
public class Coordinate 
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}
}
```

and your List as `List<Coordinate>()`
this way you can do it easily like:

```
bool exists = list.Any(l => l.X == x && x.Y == y);
```

However if you insist on having 2 separate lists, you can do it with a simple loop

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<xList.Length;i++)
{
    if(xList[i] == x && yList[i] == y) break; 
}

if(i > xList.Length)
  // not found
else
{
    //i is the index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
xList
    .Select((x, ind) => (x, (int?)ind))
    .FirstOrDefault(tuple => tuple.x == yList[tuple.ind])
    .ind ?? -1
```

We select the `xList` items as tuples of items and indices.

We get the first in the list for which the corresponding item in the other list is equal, and return the index. Because the index is `int?` we can use `?? -1` to return -1 if it is not found.

---

If you would like all possible matches, do instead:

```cs
xList
    .Select((x, ind) => (x, ind))
    .Where(tuple => tuple.x == yList[tuple.ind])
    .Select(tuple => tuple.ind)
```